# "processing classes for emulated method breakpoints" this popup comes and loading I can't debug in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

The popup is not loading fully, and I couldn't debug in my code due to that popup, causing the screen to freeze in my Android Studio Iguana 2023.2.1:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade Android studio to Hedgehog until the next patch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).